# Add href in switch case JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

When displaying a picture how to specify a redirect to the site "href"? For each picture separately link.

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.img');

for (var i = images.length; i--;) images[i].addEventListener('click', change);

function change() {
  switch (this.value) {
    case "colour1":
      image = '<img src="https://"></img>';
      break;
    case "colour2":
      image = '<img src="https://"></img>';
      break;
    case "colour3":
      image = '<img src="https://"></img>';
      break;

    default:
      image = '<img src="#!"></img>';
  }

  document.getElementById("output-image").innerHTML = image;
}
```

Comment: <input type="image" class="img" value="colour1" />
<input type="image" class="img" value="colour2" />
<input type="image" class="img" value="colour3" />
<input type="image" class="img" value="colour4" />
<input type="image" class="img" value="colour5" />
<input type="image" class="img" value="colour6" />

<div id="output-image">
</div>

Comment: When displaying a picture how to specify a redirect to the site "href"? For each picture separately link.

Comment: falcon, please edit your question instead of adding more in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to add a link to the image so it can be loaded as a seperate page you just wrap your image in an link tag with image url, if you want that link to not be a link around the image but a link itself, then add it after the image and use css to position style it as you please.

```
 var images = document.querySelectorAll('.img');

    for (var i = images.length; i--;) images[i].addEventListener('click', change);

    function change() {
      switch (this.value) {
        case "colour1":
          image = '<a target="_blank" href="https://"><img src="https://"></img></a>';
          break;
        case "colour2":
          image = '<a target="_blank" href="https://"><img src="https://"></img>';
          break;
        case "colour3":
          image = '<a target="_blank" href="https://"><img src="https://"></img>';
          break;

    default:
      image = '<a target="_blank" href="#!"><img src="#!"></img></a>';
  }

  document.getElementById("output-image").innerHTML = image;
}
```

Note i use the attribute target="_blank" to instruct the link to open a new window. If i want the link to have wording i would add it after like so:

```
<a href="https://..." target="_blank">Enlarge</a>
```